# sed replace every character in match with single character like █████ redaction

Tags: regex, sed, text-editing

Is there a sed replace function (or other Regex) that will replace every character caught by the match pattern with a single character that is meant to overlay or REDACT the matches? For instance the Full Block █ Unicode: U+2588, UTF-8: E2 96 88 would be a great choice. Is there an EASY way to do this?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text does not contain ASCII characters `0x02` and `0x03`, this:

```
sed '
s/pattern/\x02\0\x03/g
:loop
s/\x02[^\x03]/█\x02/g
t loop
s/\x02\x03//g
'
```

The characters I used are STX (start of text) and ETX (end of text) respectively. Nowadays they are rarely used in text; this makes them a good choice for temporary markers.

The solution first embraces each fragment matching the pattern with STX and ETX. Next it loops, moving each STX towards the end of line, until it meets ETX. Each such move causes `█` to appear. When each STX meets its corresponding ETX, the loop ends and finally all STX+ETX pairs are removed.

If your `sed` does not support multi-byte characters then you may get more `█`s than you expect. This will happen if whatever matches the pattern contains multi-byte characters (misinterpreted as single-byte characters). Even then, with input encoded as UTF-8, STX and ETX are safe to use, because multi-byte characters in UTF-8 consist of bytes with the highest bit being `1`, while the highest bit for STX or ETX is `0`. This means if your `sed` does not support multi-byte characters then you may get too many `█`s, but no valid UTF-8 text will interfere by accidentally being interpreted as STX or ETX (unless it's really STX or ETX, hence the initial assumption).

I tested with GNU `sed` (which does support multi-byte characters) in Linux, UTF-8 locale.

---

Example:

```
printf '%s\n' 'This is a test: CaMeL, 12a15, foo.' \
| sed '
s/[[:upper:][:digit:]]*/\x02\0\x03/g
:loop
s/\x02[^\x03]/█\x02/g
t loop
s/\x02\x03//g
'
```

The input was:

```
This is a test: CaMeL, 12a15, foo.
```

The output should be:

```
█his is a test: █a█e█, ██a██, foo.
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing every character is easy:

```
sed 's/./█/g' file
```

If your pattern is more complex, you might have to split it up. For example, if you have three words of length three you want to replace with three █:s, and two of length four, I would write two separate rules:

```
sed -e 's/\(one\|two\|six\)/███/g' -e 's/\(four\|five\)/████/g' file
```

If you have a large number of patterns of various lengths, perhaps switch to a more capable language, like Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(four score and seven years ago|all your base are belong to us|the beat goes on and I\x27m so wrong)/ "█" x length($1) /ge' file
```

(Your `sed` might have an `-E` or `-r` option which lets you avoid the backslashes, to produce a regex more like the Perl one. The regex facilities of Perl are *much* more complex than those of `sed`, so there are all kinds of additional tricks available if you switch to Perl, as well as a much more readable language for writing loops, arithmetic, etc etc. Perhaps notice also how Perl lets me write `\x27` for a literal single quote, so I don't have to fool around with the shell's quoting mechanisms to embed a literal single quote in a single-quoted string.)

Comment: A fictive -1 for "a much more readable language", I suggest to use Python for further enhanced readability.

Comment: I personally much prefer Python over Perl, but the OP seems to be looking for a simple one-liner. I would have suggested Awk as the natural next step up from `sed` but this is unnecessarily cumbersome in Awk, and extremely compact yet understandable - especially if you already know some `sed` - in Perl.